# Erlang module's syntax tree with epp:parse_file is not full and erl_parse:parse_form gives an error

Tags: erlang, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to build a script to extract some pieces of the erlang code from the source files, but my approaches don't work.
Here is what I tried:

```
{ok, Forms} = epp:parse_file("src/day_tasks.erl", [{includes, "include"}]), 
file:write_file("/projects/result.txt",
io_lib:format("~p", [Forms])).
```

This kind of worked, the AST was built, but some functions are missing in the output. The attributes for them are in place though. Instead of them I see a lot of tuples like this inside of the built syntax tree:

```
{error,{10,epp,{include,file,"cards.hrl"}}},
{error,{320,epp,{undefined,'LONG_TASK',none}}}
```

And I know that it where include attribute and where is a macro defined in the module and used in the function's body. What I don't know though is what can I do about it.

I tried another approach to get the tree, it looks like this:

```
{ok, Data} = file:read_file("src/day_tasks.erl"), 
{ok, Tokens, _Lines} = erl_scan:string(binary_to_list(Data)), 
{ok, Abs} = erl_parse:parse_form(Tokens), 
file:write_file("/projects/result1.txt", io_lib:format("~p", [Abs])).
```

But erl_parse:parse_form(Tokens) fails with the error:

```
** exception error: no match of right hand side value {error,{6,erl_parse,["syntax error before: ","'-'"]}}
```

The 6-th line is the line where the

```
-compile(export_all).
```

module attribute resides, right after module name attribute.
So here I am, I'm stuck and don't know what else can I do.

What is the right way to get fully built syntax tree for the module?

Comment: The second element of the `includes` tuple is defined to be the type  `IncludePath`, which is a list.  See if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, the first type of errors like {error,{10,epp,{include,file,"cards.hrl"}}}, is gone, but the second one still persists. I mean functions using macros are still absent.

Comment: Actually it solved both errors, thanks! I just needed to add one more path (deps) like this: {ok, Forms} = epp:parse_file("src/day_tasks.erl", [{includes, ["include", "deps"]}]), file:write_file("/projects/result.txt", io_lib:format("~p", [Forms])). Would you add an answer to this question, so I could accept it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
epp:parse_file("src/day_tasks.erl", [{includes, "include"}]),
```

The second element of the `includes` tuple is defined to be the type [IncludePath](https://erldocs.com/21.0/stdlib/epp.html?i=1&search=epp:p#parse_file/2), which is a list:

```
Options = 
    [{includes, IncludePath :: [DirectoryName :: file:name()]} |
    ...
```

[file:](https://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#type-name)name() = string() | atom() | deep_list()